# Syntax error unexpected end of file fi' what could be the cause?

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter your birthyear:  " year
read -p "Enter your birthmonth: " month


yearnow=$(date '+%Y')
monthnow=$(date '+%m')
daynow=$(date '+%d')
lastyear=$(date -d "last year" '+%Y')

agey=$(($yearnow-$year))
agem=$(($monthnow-$month))


if [ $month<$monthnow ]; then

        agem=$(($month-$monthnow)); agey=$(($lastyear-$year))
else

if [ $monthnow > $month ]; then

        agem=$(($monthnow-$month)); agey=$(($yearnow-$year))
fi

echo "You are $agey years and $agem months old."
```

I'm getting the syntax error unexpected end of file but I can't find the problem. What could it be?
I want it to calculate the age for given birthyear and birthmonth.

Comment: Use `elif` instead of `else if`.

Comment: Or another `fi` for the first `if`.  Try https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: What if the month is the same?

Comment: You can also add a second `fi` after the first `fi`, to close both of your `if` statements, although using `elif` instead of `else if` is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like this:

```
if
then
else if
     then
     fi
```

The `fi` closes the nested if-loop, but what about the first if-loop?

Your code should look like this:

```
if
then
else if
     then
     fi
fi
```

Also, good indenting might be helpful, as you can see here:

```
if [ $month<$monthnow ]; then
   agem=$(($month-$monthnow));
   agey=$(($lastyear-$year))
else if [ $monthnow > $month ]; then
        agem=$(($monthnow-$month));
        agey=$(($yearnow-$year))
     fi
```

You immediately see that there's a level with an `if` but without a `fi`.